# adding items to linked list without allowing duplicates

Tags: c, linked-list

I have to add items to a linked list without allowing any duplicates:

the list

```
typedef struct node
{
    double info;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;
```

my function:

```
   void addToEnd(NODE **lista, double info)
    {
       NODE *novi = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE));
       novi->info = info;
       novi->next = NULL;

       if (*lista == NULL)
          *lista = novi;
       else
       {
          NODE *tmp = *lista;
          while (tmp->next)
          {
            if(tmp->info == info)
            {free(new); return;}
             tmp = tmp->next;
          }
          tmp->next = novi;
       }
    }
```

It does work if the numbers aren't just besides each other, for example adding 5.5 1.0 5.5 works fine, but 5.5 5.5 1.0 adds both of the 5.5, is it a double rounding error or is the code logic flawed ?

Comment: It leaks memory if a duplicate is detected.

Comment: i fixed that, but it's not my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't allocate untill you are sure that you actually need the memory
- avoid special cases. The goal is to find the first (and only) NULL pointer in the chain. This can be `*lista` (if the list happens to be empty), or some of the `->next` pointers.

---

```
void addToEnd(NODE **lista, double info)
{
   NODE *new ;

   for (    ; *lista; lista = &(*lista)->next) {
        if((*lista)->info == info) return;
   }
   new = malloc(sizeof *new );
   new->info = info;
   new->next = NULL;
   *lista = new;
}
```

---

Or, even more compact (you don't need the `new` pointer, since you can use the `->next` pointer ):

```
void addToEnd(NODE **lista, double info)
{
   for (    ; *lista; lista = &(*lista)->next) {
        if((*lista)->info == info) return;
   }
   *lista = malloc(sizeof **lista);
   (*lista)->info = info;
   (*lista)->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: One thing, just to make sure after the for loop ends the lista is pointing to a random memory location or to a null pointer? That part confuses me

Comment: The loop condition is `*lista` ( logically the same as `*lista != NULL`) , so: after the loop, `*lista` is **guaranteed** to point to a NULL pointer.

Comment: so then you make it point to a new memory location with malloc and then assign the right value, thanks now I get it.